# Как правильно проверить наличие подключения к интернету?

Tags: java

Сейчас использую метод

```
public Boolean getInternetStatus() {
    Boolean inetStatus;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setConnectTimeout(2000);
        con.setReadTimeout(2000);
        con.connect();
        inetStatus = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        inetStatus = false;
        log.error("getInternetStatus", e);
    }

    return inetStatus;
}
```

Вроде бы работает, но проблема в том что таймаут не срабатывает. Если сайт, к которому идет обращение, висит, то коннект обрывается только через дефолтные 20 секунд. Получается что приложение зависает на 20 сек. Подскажите, как правильно установить таймаут? Возможно есть какой-то другой способ проверки подключения, чтобы обойти проблему таймаута?

Answer (score 3):

Проверить наличие соединения с интернетом - просто протестировать загружается ли какой-либо сайт или нет (можно какой-нибудь сервис WhoIs или Google)

В любом случае для проверки лучше всего использовать крупные сайты, например http://ru.stackoverflow.com или google.com. Либо проверять последовательно доступность нескольких сайтов - если хоть один из них доступен - значит соединение с интернетом присутствует.

Способ 1:

```
private static boolean checkInternetConnection() {
    Boolean result = false;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    try {            
        con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/").openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        result = (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.disconnect();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Способ 2:

(метод isReachable(), должен проверять хост в интернете на доступность)

```
public class Inet2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InetAddress in = InetAddress.getByName("http://ru.stackoverflow.com/");
        System.out.println(in.isReachable(1000) ? "Host is reachable" : "Host is NOT reachable");
    }
}
```

Способ 3:

(способ заточенный под Windows. Основан на использовании ping)

```
public class Inet3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 1 " + host);
        boolean reachable = (proc.waitFor()==0);
        System.out.println(reachable ? "Host is reachable" : "Host is NOT reachable");
    }
}
```

---

а вообще... ЗАЧЕМ ТАКАЯ ПРОВЕРКА ВООБЩЕ НУЖНА?

Вам нужен ответ от какого-то ресурса (ведь вы хотите куда-то обратиться) - попытайтесь обратиться сразу, без проверок доступности интернета.
Если в ходе подключения появится ошибка - обработайте ее через try, выведите сообщение:

"Пардон, пацаны, интернет не подключен!"